# pip upgrade not happening in python 2.7

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am in confusion. I have looked in other posts in regard to this problem. In terminal of conda env., when I ran

```
conda list
```

all the packages are displayed with versions. pip version is 8.0.2

When I tried

```
 python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

The cursor move to next line and blinks for long time.
I intend to update pip . The above line is suppose to upgrade pip. Am I missing something and what are possible solutions.

Comment: How long is a long time? Python / PIP occasionally take quite a long time to open for me too. A couple of days ago  PIP did seem to crash the terminal, a reboot fixed it. Also, what platform are you on?

Comment: try `conda update pip`.

Comment: On my last run it took more than 5hrs and still counting.. So I aborted..

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Upgrade all packages with pip:

```
import pip
from subprocess import call

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    call("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```